# Iteration over a big std::vector

Tags: c++11, vector, iteration

I have a C++ vector of tuples. The tuples consist of three doubles and one integer. The vector may contain hundreds of thousands of elements. Even using the C++11 for(auto element : vector){} loop, I manage to iterate over no more than about 100k elements. Is there any other solution for iterating over the whole "big" vector (currently 275k elements)?
My code:

```
    for(auto record : rD)
    {
//      Find indices:
        indxSc  = std::get<2>(record) - 1;
        indxSp  = static_cast<int>( std::get<0>(record)/0.3 );
        if(indxSp > 47 )indxSp = 46;
        indxDir = findSector72( std::get<1>(record) );

//      Increment counts in bins
        ++cntSit[indxSc][indxSp][indxDir];
        ++cntSpeed[indxSp];

//      Add reciprocal of wind speed to sum for <1/u>
        valSpeed[indxSp] = valSpeed[indxSp] + 1./( std::get<0>(record) );
    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what size is each element in that vector and where do they come from (like, a file on the disk, the internet...)?

Comment: *I manage to iterate over no more than about 100k elements* what does that mean exactly? Loops don't just terminate out of nowhere. Also, use `for(const auto& record : rD)` instead of making a copy each time.

Comment: How do you know it only iterates over about 100k elements? What happens at runtime? Does the loop just stop? Does it continue with the statements after the loop? Please elaborate with as much details as you can.

Comment: limitation is weird.. do you have time constraint? And why using tuples, not a  struct, for this particular case, when you know what structure will be?  You may look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691459/how-do-i-parallelize-a-for-loop-through-a-c-stdlist-using-openmp

Comment: Thanks everybody! I started from the scratch and I can "reproduce" the full vector and print it into a file. Hence, the trouble is somewhere in my code inside, perhaps division by zero. Thanks for reminding me to pass by reference using the 'const auto& record : rD' option. I shall build the code step by step, which is the best practice anyway. Thanks again! My working looks like this:

Comment: for(const auto& record : rD)
    {
        test << std::get<0>(record) << '\t' <<
                std::get<1>(record) << '\t' <<
                std::get<2>(record) << '\t' <<
                std::get<3>(record) << '\n';
 }