# Trying to process linked list data in parallel with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp, singly-linked-list

I am trying to process linked list data in parallel with OpenMP in C++.  I'm pretty new to OpenMP and pretty rusty with C++.  What I want to do is get several threads to break up the linked list, and output the data of the Nodes in their particular range.  I don't care about the order in which the output occurs.  If I can get this working, I want to replace the simple output with some actual processing of the Node data.

I've found several things on the internet (including a few questions on this site) and from what I found, I cobbled together a code like this:

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <omp.h>

        // various and sundry other stuff ...

        struct Node {
                int data;
                Node* next;
        };

        int main() {

            struct Node *newHead;
            struct Node *head = new Node;
            struct Node *currNode;
            int n;
            int tid;

            //create a bunch of Nodes in linked list with "data" ...

            // traverse the linked list:
            // examine data
            #pragma omp parallel private(tid)
            {
            currNode = head;
            tid=omp_get_thread_num();
            #pragma omp single
            {
            while (currNode) {
               #pragma omp task firstprivate(currNode)
               {
               cout << "Node data: " << currNode->data << " " << tid << "\n";
               } // end of pragma omp task
               currNode = currNode->next;
            } // end of while
            } //end of pragma omp single

            }  // end of pragma omp parallel


    // clean up etc. ...

    }  // end of main
```

So I run:

```
>: export OMP_NUM_THREADS=6
>: g++ -fopenmp ll_code.cpp
>: ./a.out
```

And the output is:

```
Node data: 5 0
Node data: 10 0
Node data: 20 0
Node data: 30 0
Node data: 35 0
Node data: 40 0
Node data: 45 0
Node data: 50 0
Node data: 55 0
Node data: 60 0
Node data: 65 0
Node data: 70 0
Node data: 75 0
```

So, tid is always 0.  And that means, unless I'm really misunderstanding something, only one thread did anything with the linked list, and so the linked list was not traversed in parallel at all.

When I get rid of `single`, the code fails with a seg fault.  I have tried moving a few variables in and out of the OpenMP directive scopes, with no change.  Changing the number of threads has no effect.  How can this be made to work?

A secondary question: Some sites say the `firstprivate(currNode)` is necessary and others say `currNode` is `firstprivate` by default.  Who is right?

Comment: A linked list is an innately serial structure, so it's hard to see multi-threading can help with traversing one.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I understand your point, but there are alot of sites out there that say its possible and that this (if I can get it to work!) is the way to do it.  Maybe the key is to emphasize what I said in my question, that I don't care what order the output comes in.  So each thread could start at a different spot and just do its "local" traversal until it gets to the spot where the next thread started (or the end of the list).

Comment: "So each thread could start at a different spot" - how could it find where to start without traversing the list?

Comment: @NeilButterworth  Again, I completely get your point.  There are alot of people out there who think differently, though.  See for example http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/Intro_To_OpenMP_Mattson.pdf starting a p. 127 and p. 142.

Comment: You have neither multiple tasks nor a loop that OpenMP can run in parallel.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  I get it.  But the sites where I got this code from claim that tasks can make the extra coding of "tossing out tasks" unnecessary.  See for example openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/Intro_To_OpenMP_Mattson.pdf starting a p. 127 and p. 142.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parallelize a for loop through a C++ std::list using OpenMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691459/how-do-i-parallelize-a-for-loop-through-a-c-stdlist-using-openmp)

Comment: @Zulan  Very sorry.  I got dinged with that question yesterday, when I hadn't made quite as much progress.  That is one of the questions I was looking at to construct my own code.  I have read it and gotten all I can out of it, and I'm still having trouble.  Your patience is appreciated.

Comment: I see now the issue was something entirely different. I didn't catch that on my first look. Now we you have an excellent answer here by Cássio Renan. But 99% of this answer is exactly the answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can traverse a linked list using multiple threads, but it will be actually slower than just using a single thread.

The reason is that, to know the address of a node `N != 0`, you must know the address of node `N-1`.

Assume now that you have `N` threads, each responsible for "starting at `i` position". The above paragraph implies that a thread `i` will depend on the result of thread `i-1`, which in turn will depend on the result of thread `i-2`, and so on.

What you end up with is a serial traversal anyway. But now, instead of just a simple `for`, you have to synchronize threads too, making things inherently slower.

But, if you're trying to do some heavy processing that would benefit from being run in parallel, then yes, you're going for the right approach. You can just change how you're getting the thread id:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

struct Node {
        int data;
        Node* next;
};

int main() {

    struct Node *head = new Node;
    struct Node *currNode = head;

    head->data = 0;
    for (int i=1;i<10;++i) {
        currNode->next = new Node;
        currNode = currNode->next;
        currNode->data = i;
    }

    // traverse the linked list:
    // examine data
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        currNode = head;
        #pragma omp single
        {
            while (currNode) {
               #pragma omp task firstprivate(currNode)
               {
                   #pragma omp critical (cout)
                   std::cout << "Node data: " << currNode->data << " " << omp_get_thread_num() << "\n";
               }
               currNode = currNode->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
Node data: 0 4
Node data: 6 4
Node data: 7 4
Node data: 8 4
Node data: 9 4
Node data: 1 3
Node data: 2 5
Node data: 3 2
Node data: 4 1
Node data: 5 0
```

### [See it live!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7630dcb568b18a16)

Finally, for a more idiomatic approach, consider using a [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list):

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {

    std::forward_list<int> list;
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i) list.push_front(i);

    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    for(auto data : list) {
       #pragma omp task firstprivate(data)
       #pragma omp critical (cout)
       std::cout << "Node data: " << data << " " << omp_get_thread_num() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but something is really weird.  I copied and pasted your first code directly and ran it.  I still get the same thread at every output.  For some reason, it's not thread 0 in every run.  But in one run it's all 0, then in the next all 4, etc.  I added an omp_get_num_threads() to make sure I was actually running on more than one thread, and that looked OK.  Thank you for your help.  I don't know what's going on.  Am I running into some weird system problem?

Comment: @bob.sacamento Nothing guarantees multiple threads will be used (Why should it? All you want is the processing to be completed as fast as possible, right?). If your processing is too fast, it may just be that the same thread is being reused on each iteration. This may certainly be the case in this snippet, as all that's being done is printing an integer to STDOUT. Try testing this with some actual processing that may take some time to complete.

Comment: @CássioRenan  Thanks very much for your continued help.  I added some dummy processing that takes a noticeable amount of time (~ 0.25 sec) per Node.  No change with regard to thread parallelism.  Does this still sound reasonable?  Thanks again.

Comment: @CássioRenan  OK.  Switched to another system.  Saw clear parallelism.  So you are right and I am accepting your answer.  Thanks!